# Pandas Group By Split, get user input, add column to subset, merge back to df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a df that needs values based on user input. This will be part of a program that runs different data each time. The code I am having trouble with is

```
for A, new_df in data.groupby(level=0):
    print A
    tariff=get_tariff()
    this=data.iloc[data.index.get_level_values('A') == A]
    #this adds a new column
    this['Tariff Added']= this['Price'] * tariff
    pd.merge(data, this)
```

I have two levels of indexes.  I split the data on the appropriate level, then I get the user input.  Here is were I can't figure it out. I need each level=0 to make a new column.  In this code, this becomes a df were level = 0 is only the appropriate value. Then I want to merge it back to the original df (I realize that the merge may not be right, I am taking this one step at a time).

When I run this in the terminal, I get this

```
data_load.py:35: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  this['Tariff Added']= this['Price'] * tariff
```

And then a failure.  I am not sure why it says I am making a copy, and I am using .iloc to declare a new df, and merge it to the original.

An idea I had is to make the 'Tariff Added' column before I start, but I wanted to check here to see why this code is not working.

The df I am working with is this

```
                      Quantity  Price
A             B                    
NB Well     123n5/15       100      1
            123n5/15       200      2
            123n5/15       300      3
            456n5/15       100      1
            456n5/15       200      2
            456n5/15       300      3
excito      123n5/15       100      1
            123n5/15       200      2
            123n5/15       300      3
            456n5/15       100      1
            456n5/15       200      2
            456n5/15       300      3
```

Comment: What is recommended output?

Comment: @jezrael I need a new column that has a different value depending on the A index